# why constructors need scope resolution to define it outside the body?

Tags: c++

if we declare a member function of a class inside the class and write its definition outside of class , then it is understood that we need to use scope resolution operator since there might be n number of functions of same name in other class...

```
//assume required header libraries included
class temp{
int x;
public:
void outp();
};
class qwerty{
int x;
public:
void outp()
{ std::cout<<x;}
};
void temp::outp()
{ std::cout<<x; }
```

but since class name is always unique... so constructor name would also be unique so why we still need to use scope resolution in defining constructor outside the class body

```
class temp{
int x;
temp();
};
temp::temp(){
x=0;
}
```

and not directly

```
temp(){
x=0;
}
```

or perhaps

```
::temp(){
x=0
};
```

like i know in c++ we need to use scope resolution for things out of scope...so why not the above code...?

Comment: ...because `temp()` could also be an unrelated free function?

Comment: `temp() { ... }` looks like a function that is missing the return type and `::temp() { ... }` looks like something messing with the global namespace (i.e., `::`) ...

Comment: @JamesAdkison ...it wont mess up... global namespace is done diferently... as in using namespace std; .. the standard one we use...i think it wont mess up with it...

Comment: consistency? It looks like the language is not complicated enough for you. Well, good luck on your journey...

Comment: @ShreyanMehta I wasn't saying it would break anything but a function in the global namespace can be explicitly called (i.e., `::myGlobalFunc();`).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath firstly thank you for your comment ... secondly yeah it is a bit complicated as specially the c++ 2011 one...c++98 was very normal...thirdly... the thing is that is not an excuse one can give for it... and also... already c++ has given and made things a little different for constructors from beginning itself... like function with no return type... not even void... see now that is also hurting the feeling of consistency perhaps...

Comment: @JamesAdkison ...sure it can be.... but at this point of time i aint talking about calling it up.... i m rather more concern about defining it... and since function call and defination ...compiler can take care of there differences...what do you think mate??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the early days of C, you didn't have to explicitly specify a return type for a function. If you didn't, it was assumed to be `int`. When C++ evolved, it needed to be backwards compatible with C, and there were already many C programs which relied on this behavior to some extent. For many years, even though not specifying a return type had become an error both in C and in C++, compilers still only generated warnings for it, probably to avoid breaking existing code.

Hence, at that time, writing something like

```
MyClass() { /* ... */ }
```

might have been interpreted as a function `int MyClass(void)`. And if you wrote a class, you didn't want to conflict with that function.

Also, since the constructor *is* a function, after all, it makes sense to treat all member function definitions consistently.

Comment: relatively better and satisfying answer to me till now...to be true when i was putting up this question i dint had this C point in mind... after reading it... i have an counter question to it...that is...many... like hell lot many things have been changed...in compilers as well as languages... so if only this was the reason than i think this would too had changed acc. to me... since many less relevant things have changed ever since...

Comment: @ShreyanMehta When did anything change that broke backward compatibility?

Comment: @ShreyanMehta Not necessarily. C++ tends to be *very* conservative when it comes to breaking changes.

Comment: there are many examples for the same... like void main is not allowed in new compilers...also that these things also depends on compiler to compiler...

Comment: @ShreyanMehta It's a bit different. `void main()` was *never* allowed in any standard. Nor have implicit return types been allowed. I think the safer thing to say is that C++ is very conservative when it comes to breaking *standardized* behavior.

Comment: @ShreyanMehta If something changes from compiler to compiler, then it is implementation defined. That means that the C++ standard does not care how it is done. The things that are defined in the C++ standard don't tend to change very often and usually keep backwards compatibility.

Comment: yeah it is safer...but void main() was allowed in c++ in turbo c++...like i know about that atleast... also we dont need to do using namespace std;.... and many other changes...

Comment: @ShreyanMehta Once again, it's actually *standardized* behavior that is meant to be stable. If tomorrow some new compiler vendor decides to roll out new syntax, and then in a later version it deprecates it, we don't say that C++ has changed. C++ here means the formally standardized form of the language.

Comment: @YamMarcovic  i gave an example...more over there are changes from c++ 98 to c++ 2011... check this out... [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Core_language_runtime_performance_enhancements]

Comment: @ShreyanMehta I think I see what you mean: Why not also add a new constructor syntax (without deprecating the old), while breaking something that was never standard (which still happens). I guess that this is a trade-off that isn't considered to be important enough. It _will_ break code, and the benefits it gives are pretty minor, and even its aesthetics (which is their only upside) is questionable, since it breaks the present consistency with member function declarations.

Comment: @YamMarcovic...i think i would go with your last cmnt... i agree what u said... that it has a minor benefit is guess and aesthetics would change...i marked this answer most appropriate ...xd... btw thank you guys for sharing your views on it...